# Capture variable when exception occurs

Tags: php, magento

I have this error:

[Wed Jul 25 15:48:09 2012] [error] [client 50.xxx.xxx.xxx] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php on line 1389

In this function:

```
/**
 * Get attribute text by its code
 *
 * @param $attributeCode Code of the attribute
 * @return string
 */
public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)
{
    return $this->getResource()
       ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
            ->getSource()
                ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
}
```

And I want to log the $attributeCode value whenever the error occurs. So I change the function to this:

```
public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)
{
    try {
        return $this->getResource()
           ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
                ->getSource()
                    ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($attributeCode);
        throw($e);
    }
}
```

…and restart Apache, yet nothing shows up in the server.log. If I comment out the throw($e), the exception still gets thrown.

./lib/Zend/Rest/Server.php has set_exception_handler(array($this, "fault"));

But please tell me php doesn't ignore all manual exception handling once you set that somewhere. Because that would be crazy.

Any idea how I can capture the $attributeCode only when the exception happens?

Comment: Php cannot catch fatal errors in try catch block. You can define php behavior for uncatch exception in set_exception_handler function, so if you want then "php can ignore all exceptions" - this change affects global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$attributes = $this->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode);
if (!empty($attributes)) {
    return $attributes->getSource()->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
} else {
    Mage::log($attributeCode);
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('bla bla');
}
```

// I do not know what is returned by getAttribute($attributeCode); so instead of empty() you can use is_null(), isset()

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes only, I would do this:

```
if (!is_object($this->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode)) {
    var_dump($attributeCode);
    exit();
}
```